# Why can't I use an analytic (window) function with GROUP BY? e.g. first_value, any_value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to evaluate this query:

```sql
SELECT
  dim1,
  dim2,
  first_value(dim3) over (partition by dim1, dim2 order by m1 desc) as top_dim3,
  sum(m1) as m1,
  avg(m2) as m2
FROM
  [TABLE_ID]
GROUP BY
  dim1,
  dim2
```

I get an error:

> SELECT list expression references column page which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Fair enough, but when I try to remedy it by adding `top_dim3` to the GROUP BY, I get this error:

> Column top_dim3 contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY

I'm wondering why this is the case. Is it purely a limitation of SQL or is there a deeper concept that I'm not understanding?

I'll note that I can use an inner-select to accomplish what I want:

```sql
SELECT
  dim1,
  dim2,
  top_dim3,
  sum(m1) as m1,
  avg(m2) as m2
FROM (
  SELECT
    dim1, dim2, m1, m2,
    first_value(dim3) over (partition by dim1, dim2 order by m1 desc) as top_dim3
  FROM [TABLE_ID]
)      
GROUP BY
  dim1,
  dim2,
  top_dim3
```

My intuition is that I should avoid inner selects. For one reason readability of my query. Is there another reason why I should be weary of using an inner select like this?

I'm writing BigQuery SQL but curious about these questions for SQL databases in general.

---

EDIT:

Having played around a bit more, I found that another solution in BigQuery is to use `HAVING`, i.e.

```sql
SELECT
  dim1,
  dim2,
  any_value(dim3 having max(m1)) as top_dim3,
  sum(m1) as m1,
  avg(m2) as m2
FROM
  [TABLE_ID]
GROUP BY
  dim1,
  dim2
```

Comment: You should put your solution as an answer below, not as part of the question. You are free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytical functions and aggregate functions are very different in SQL.

Normal aggregate functions need a `GROUP BY`, and at the point when they are invoked, there only exists either the `GROUP BY` columns, or aggregations of the other columns. No other column usage is allowed.

Analytical functions, meanwhile, work on a per-row basis, so when you use it in a query that already has a `GROUP BY`, it works on the *already aggregated* result. This means you can only use an analytical function in such a query using the same rules as other `SELECT` columns: only the `GROUP BY` or an aggregation.

> Incidentally, this means you can use windowing *over* aggregation, eg `SUM(SUM(...)) OVER (...)`

So when you try and use `FIRST_VALUE` in an aggregation, it can only use such columns, it cannot use non-aggregated or non-grouped columns.

I suppose it could be conceived that it should exist as an aggregation function also, using syntax such as `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY`, but this is not in the SQL standard yet.

---

Your new query isn't quite right though: it's going to be inefficient due to the grouping over the `FIRST_VALUE` result. Instead, *aggregate* that using `MIN`

```sql
SELECT
  dim1,
  dim2,
  min(top_dim3) as top_dim3,
  sum(m1) as m1,
  avg(m2) as m2
FROM (
  SELECT
    dim1, dim2, m1, m2,
    first_value(dim3) over (partition by dim1, dim2 order by m1 desc rows unbounded preceding) as top_dim3
  FROM [TABLE_ID]
) t
GROUP BY
  dim1,
  dim2;
```

You can also do this using `ROW_NUMBER` and conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  dim1,
  dim2,
  min(case when rn = 1 then dim3 end) as top_dim3,
  sum(m1) as m1,
  avg(m2) as m2
FROM (
  SELECT
    dim1, dim2, m1, m2,
    row_number() over (partition by dim1, dim2 order by m1 desc) as rn
  FROM [TABLE_ID]
) t
GROUP BY
  dim1,
  dim2;
```

As to using such a subquery: no this isn't an issue for most good optimizers. What you do need to be aware of is re-sorting the results as mentioned. Also unless you use  `rows unbounded preceding`, it may be slow to use `first_value` in some systems.

Comment: "when you use it in a query that already has a GROUP BY, it works on the already aggregated result" This is particularly insightful!

Comment: Your `WITHIN GROUP` idea got me thinking, and I was surprised that if I use `HAVING` then I can use a window function, i.e. `ANY_VALUE(dim3 HAVING max(m1))` fixes my first SQL statement (using BigQuery)

Comment: I'm not sure what that even means: it's non-standard SQL, it seems similar to `FILTER` in Postgres, but certainly aggregates within aggregates are not allowed by it or by most other DBMSs. Not so familiar with BigQuery though.

Comment: I added an example at the bottom of my post. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!